# Laravel 5 model class not found - hasMany

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get company employees using the has many method in model. But I get this error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Employee' not found (View: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/resources/views/frontpage.blade.php)
```

Here is my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Company;
use App\Employee;

    public function index()
    {
        $data = Company::get();
        $data = array(
            'companies' => $data,
        );


        return view('frontpage', $data);
    }
```

And here is my models: first one is Company.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Employee;

class Company extends Model{

    protected $table = 'company';

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Employee', 'company_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Here is the other model, Employee.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model{

    public $table = "employee";

}
```

And here is the view

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div>
    @foreach ($companies as $company)
        <p>This is company {{ $company->name }}</p>
        <p>{{ print_r($company->employee) }}</p>
    @endforeach
</div>

@stop
```

Comment: Why don't you pass `companies` directly like so from the controller
`public function index()
    {
        $companies = Company::get();
        return view('frontpage', compact('companies'));
    }` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Relation definitions require fully qualified class names to be passed.

Replace

```
return $this->hasMany('Employee', 'company_id', 'id');
```

with either

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Employee', 'company_id', 'id');
```

or

```
return $this->hasMany(Employee::class, 'company_id', 'id');
```